# C# dynamically casting an object based on the return value of GetType()

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to codding in C#, and i am '*diving in the deep*' with this question...

In the following code, in the `foreach` loop on first pass the value of `item.Name` is equal to 'BB', and the value of `item.GetValue(b)` returns 'ConsoleApp.A'.

How can i get the details of `item.GetValue(b)`?

I know that:

- `item.GetValue(b).GetType().ToString()` returns "ConsoleApp42.A"
- `((A)item.GetValue(b)).AA` returns "11"

How can i do this `((A)item.GetValue(b)).AA` dynamically? In this example it always results in a `class A` object, but in my real life code this can be a choice of several classes...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A() { AA=11, BB=22, CC=33 } ;
        B b = new B() { BB = a, CC = 2, DD = 1 };
     
        foreach (var item in b.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}  Value:{1}", item.Name, item.GetValue(b));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class A {
    public int AA { get; set; }
    public int BB { get; set; }
    public int CC { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public A BB { get; set; }
    public int CC { get; set; }
    public int DD { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or like this?

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A() { a1 = 11, a2 = 22, a3 = 33 };
            C c = new C() { c1 = 111, c2 = 222, c3 = 333 };
            B b = new B() { b1 = a, b2 = c, b3 = 1 };

            //iterate through b's properties
            foreach (var item in b.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var d = b.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name);
                var e = d.GetValue(b);

                //here we iterate through a's and c's properties (from b object)
                //it will print it's properties dynamically
                foreach (var f in e.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Value: {1}", f.Name, f.GetValue(e)) ;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class A
        {
            public int a1 { get; set; }
            public int a2 { get; set; }
            public int a3 { get; set; }
        }

        class B
        {
            public A b1 { get; set; }
            public C b2 { get; set; }
            public int b3 { get; set; }
        }

        class C
        {
            public int c1 { get; set; }
            public int c2 { get; set; }
            public int c3 { get; set; }
        }
```

Outputs:

```cs
Name: a1 Value: 11
Name: a2 Value: 22
Name: a3 Value: 33
Name: c1 Value: 111
Name: c2 Value: 222
Name: c3 Value: 333
```

Comment: It look so easy, thanks..... now i wil have to find out if i can apply this to my real life code!

Answer (score 0):

Check the type and cast it at the same type with `as`. If the item isn't an A then `as` will return `null`, so you can use the coalesce operator (`??`) to determine what to output.

```
foreach (var item in b.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    object rawValue = item.GetValue(b);
    A typedValue = rawValue as A;
    string output = (typedValue?.AA ?? rawValue).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}  Value:{1}", output );

}
```

or (this might be easier to follow):

```
foreach (var item in b.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    object rawValue = item.GetValue(b);
    A typedValue = rawValue as A;
    if (typedValue == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:{0} Value:{1}", rawValue);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Name:{0} Value:{1}", typedValue.AA);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am missing the answer part from this piece of my question "but in my real life code this can be a choice of several classes". If `A` (as example in this question) could possibly be any of a lot of different classes, than this would be awful to program..... 

Comment: You asked about *casting*. You cannot cast, by definition, unless you write type-specific code for the cast. If there are numerous possible types involved, that is what [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) is for.

Comment: True, the word 'cast' is in the subject of the question. I think the other answer (which i marked as answer) will solve my problem. Thanks for you input anyway!